# Как вычислить СЛАУ итерационным методом

Tags: c#, .net

Нужно решить СЛАУ итерационным методом.
Методы уже все имеются, просто нужно правильно в файле программ их применить

```
Console.WriteLine("Есть матрица А");

        double[,] A = { 
                      { 2, 1 }, 
                      { 1, -2 } 
                      };

        Matrix.dispMartix(A);

        Console.WriteLine("и eё вектор решений");
        double[] B = { 3, 1 };
        Matrix.dispVec(B);

        Console.WriteLine();

        double[] C;
        C = SLAU.solveByInv(A,B);
        Matrix.dispVec(C);
        double tor=10;
        double[] C1;
        C1 = SLAU.iteration(A,B,tor);
        Matrix.dispVec(C1);
```

Сами методы

```
public static double[] solveByInv(double[,] A, double[] b)
    {
        double[] res = new double[b.GetLength(0)];
        res = Matrix.multMatToVec(Matrix.invertMatrix(A), b);
        return res;
    }


    public static double findMaxDiff(double[] V1, double[] V2)
    {
        double[] diff = Matrix.addVecToVec(V1, Matrix.multVecToNumb(V2, -1));

        double res = Math.Abs(diff[0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < diff.GetLength(0) - 1; i++) {
            if (Math.Abs(diff[i + 1]) >= diff[i]) {
                res = Math.Abs(diff[i + 1]);
            }
        }

        return res;
    }


    public static double[] iteration(double[,] c, double[] b, double eps)
    {
        double[] result = new double[c.GetLength(0)];
        double[] previousRes = new double[result.GetLength(0)];
        double normC = 0;
        for (int row = 0; row < c.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < c.GetLength(1); col++)
            {
                normC += Math.Pow(c[row, col], 2);
            }
        }
        normC = Math.Sqrt(normC);
        if (normC > 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Есть решение");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Решений нет");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < previousRes.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            previousRes[i] = 0;
        }
        double max = -1;
        // итерац. проц Xi+1=Cxi+b
        do
        {
            max = -1;
            result = Matrix.addVecToVec(Matrix.multMatToVec(c, previousRes), b);
            max = SLAU.findMaxDiff(result, previousRes);
            for (int i = 0; i < result.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                previousRes[i] = result[i];
            }
        }
        while (max > eps);
        return result;
    }
```

Как их правильно применить?
Также уже написано куча других методов, для работы с матрицами.

Comment: Ну дак у вас уже пример вызова метода есть `  C1 = SLAU.iteration(A,B,tor);`

Comment: Разберитесь с теорией СЛАУ, затем разберитесь с C# затем вы поймет какие параметры передаются в методы, вызваете методы с верными параметрами. Получаете решение введеных  СЛАУ

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример того, как вызвать метод. Перед этим не забудьте подключить класс SLAU, который описан в «вашем коде».

```
double[] C1;
double[,] A1;
double [] B;
double eps = 12;

double[,] A = { 
    { 8, 5 }, 
    { 5, -9 } 
};

Matrix.dispMartix(A);
double[] B = { 6, 2 };

Matrix.dispVec(B);

C1= SLAU.iteration(A,B,eps);
```